# Setting page zoom and text size in IE programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, automation

I need to write a small executable which loads IE8 with a specific URL, but also sets the page zoom to default and text size to default (medium).

I can hackishly set the page zoom by sending the *ctrl+0* keystroke to the IE window, but there's not really any easy way that I can see to set the text size.

I could go through the menu with keystrokes: *alt+z -> x -> m* but this is just getting silly. I have no way of knowing whether the menu has shown and whether it's safe to send the next key.

I've looked at the IE command line arguments, but they're really limited.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Zoom`. You can set a DWORD that corresponds to the zoom level of the page.

Comment: I will not have access to edit the registry on the target machines.

Comment: What are you using to launch IE on the target machine? How are you able to launch IE but not have access to HKCU?

Comment: Editing the registry requires UAC authorisation, whereas running any process can be done at any time. Anyway, this is irrelevant. The registry key your are referring to is for the page zoom which is easy to do with ctrl+0. The big problem I'm having is with text size.